# Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two UIViewAutoresizing operands

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift2

Getting this error in Swift 2.0.

> Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two UIViewAutoresizing operands

Here is the code:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568))
addSubview(view)
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
```

Any idea what can be the problem?
[image]

Comment: Effectively the same problem as in [Swift 2.0 - Binary Operator “|” cannot be applied to two UIUserNotificationType operands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype).

Answer (score 465, accepted):

The `OptionSetType` got an updated syntax for Swift 2.x and another update for Swift 3.x

**Swift 3.x**

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

**Swift 2.x**

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

Answer (score 29):

This are the differences between Swift 1.2 and 2:

```
// swift 1.2
view.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleTopMargin

// swift 2
view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleTopMargin]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try with xcode7-b6:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth.union(UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight)
```

Answer (score 5):

For `Swift 3` `Xcode 8 b1`:

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Comment: @Pushpa: curious, other than adding the word "For" at the front of my answer, did you edit/change something else that I cannot see? Thanks

Comment: Yes, putted the code inside code block :) And yes this answer is already posted with Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

actual for swift 3.0.2:

```
view.autoresizingMask = [.layerWidthSizable, .layerHeightSizable]
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code swift 2 with Xcode 7.2

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleRightMargin, .FlexibleLeftMargin, .FlexibleBottomMargin, .FlexibleTopMargin]
```