# Binary Operator Cannot be Applied to two SCNDebugOptions

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am just trying to set two flags for the debug options. Why is this a problem in Swift 4

[image]

Comment: Same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867325/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiviewautoresizing-operands (from the "Related" section).

Answer (score 9):

instead of doing "`|`", use a set:

```
sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints,ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]
```

Answer (score 0):

`SCNDebugOptions` confirm the protocol `OptionSet`, which confirm `SetAlgebra` protocol and `SetAlgebra` confirm `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` protocol.

```
public struct SCNDebugOptions : OptionSet {...}
protocol OptionSet : RawRepresentable, SetAlgebra {...}
public protocol SetAlgebra : Equatable, ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {...}
```

That's why you can't use the pipe (`|`) sign for multiple arguments. instead, use an array.

```
sceneView.debugOptions = [.showFeaturePoints, .showWorldOrigin]
```